# Error durin compilation Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 76.0 MiB

There is an error in vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/CharacterData.php at line: 15
Interface "Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\CharacterDataInterface" not found#0 vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(578): include()

what can be a problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit, you have a piece of code using `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\CharacterDataInterface` which do not exist in your vendor.

Two possibilities :

1. This is a class removed in this magento version and that you are still calling in custom code.
   **solution:** if that so you need to correct it.
2. your vendor is not properly installed for this magento version.
   **solution:** composer install.